# Socket io + MTQQ

Tags: android, ios, socket.io, mqtt

Is there any nice library for a websocket and mqtt protocol for building mobile apps on android or iphone?

Or just a good supported one on android?

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

For Android just take a look at the Paho Android Service
https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/

For iOS you should figure out how to implement Paho C++ 
https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/cpp/

Or also Paho Embedded C/C++
https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/c/embedded/